# MySQL: Schedule event 15 minutes after table insert

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot

In my booking database, there is a `RentOrder` table with an `orderStatus` column. Users can access and make orders via a booking api.

I want MySQL to wait 15 minutes after an initial `RentOrder` insert and check if `orderStatus` is still set to `RESERVED` (i.e. check if the order hasn't been confirmed). If this is the case, then I want to automatically set the orderStatus to `TIMEOUT`.

My idea so far is to user `AFTER INSERT` and `SLEEP` but I'm not sure this is optimal? My main concern is that `SLEEP` might have some adverse effects on performance or anything else.

Any suggestions welcome and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* set an event.  Personally, I recommend a view for this purpose:

```
create view v_RentOrder as
    select . . .,
           (case when createdAt < now() - interval 15 minute and orderStatus = 'RESERVED'
                 then 'TIMEOUT'
                 else orderStatus
            end) as orderStatus
    from RentOrder;
```

The column `createdAt` is the time the record was created.

Voila!  The data is always up-to-date -- to the second -- for anyone using the view.

You can pair this with a job that periodically (say once per day or once per hour) updates the table with the status that you want.

The option of creating an event or job for every update has challenges:

- If the database goes down, updates may not take effect.
- If there is a heavy server load, updates may be delayed.
- If the table or rows are locked, the updates may be delayed.
- The `update`s increase the load on the system and might interfere with other activities.

These problems can be mitigated by using a queuing/messaging system for the updates.  However, that starts to get complicated for a simple problem.

Comment: Elegant solution which optimises for performance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create event procedure which fires with safe time granularity (for example, each 10 second) and updates the rows which matches your condition as needed.

---

> My idea so far is to user AFTER INSERT and SLEEP

Do it never. Trigger code must be as fast as possible. If trigger contains `SLEEP(x)` then each row will take `x` second for insertion.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id int);
> ```

> ```
> -- no trigger, fast insertion
> SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) INTO @CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
> SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3), @CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
> ```
>
> ```
> | TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3), @CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) |
> | :------------------------------------------------- |
> | 00:00:00.002000                                    |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi BEFORE INSERT ON test
> FOR EACH ROW
> SELECT NEW.id + SLEEP(2) INTO @tmp;
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai AFTER INSERT ON test
> FOR EACH ROW
> SELECT NEW.id + SLEEP(3) INTO @tmp;
> ```

> ```
> -- 2 triggers with SLEEP, over 2+3=5 second per row insertion
> SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) INTO @CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
> SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3), @CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
> ```
>
> ```
> | TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3), @CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) |
> | :------------------------------------------------- |
> | 00:00:05.003000                                    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffc67916d980589ec3a84d032e787785)*